# MySQL IN() with subquery stopped working?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view called "v_documents" where a i have a field "document_type_name" that is based on some fields. However the field is a string with a name.

Now i want all documents where the type name is contained in another table. But...

This work:

```
SELECT * FROM v_documents WHERE document_type_name IN ('PREVENTIVO', 'FATTURA');
```

This not:

```
SELECT * FROM v_documents WHERE document_type_name IN (
     SELECT type FROM t_types
);
```

Where `t_types` contains a list of document types and nothing more.
It give me 0 records.

But if i use `=` istead of `IN()` and i return only one record from the subquery it works.

The problem is that if i'm not wrong this code worked before. I don't know what is happening.

P.S The `t_types` table **DON'T HAVE** null values!

**EDIT**: using the subquery in a field seems work. Why in the IN() not?

Here a screen: on the left the subquery used as field, on the right the return records from `SELECT type FROM t_types`

[image]

**EDIT 2**: Screen for @MatBailie's answere. But i used a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because i get a MySQL error.

[image]

Comment: try trim if there any space issue    SELECT * FROM v_documents WHERE trim(document_type_name) IN (
     SELECT trim(type_ FROM t_types
);

Comment: Can you show us the output of the `t_types`?

Comment: @Mauro can u please specify some table data

Comment: Can you show output of this query "SELECT type FROM t_types" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only half an answer, but too long for a comment.

I would begin by using the following query to directly compare what is in each table...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT('[', document_type_name, ']') AS document_type_name
  FROM
    v_documents
  GROUP BY
    document_type_name
)
  AS documents
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    CONCAT('[', type, ']') AS type
  FROM
    t_types
  GROUP BY
    type
)
  AS types
    ON types.type = documents.document_type_name
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(document_type_name, type)
```

This will show every type that exists in both tables, with what matches and what doesn't.  The concatenation of the `'['` and `']'` will help spot leading/trailing spaces.

I'd love to see the results in your question.

**EDIT :**

And you are *certain* that the following does not work?  *(Exactly as is, with no other changes or additions?)*

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  v_documents
WHERE
  document_type_name IN (SELECT type FROM t_types)
```

If so, I can't explain it.  The existence of *any* matches from the first query "proves" *(or so I thought)* that the `IN (SELECT)` version should be fine.

That said, here are some alternatives.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  v_documents
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t_types WHERE t_types.type = v_documents.document_type_name)
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  v_documents.*
FROM
  v_documents
INNER JOIN
  t_types
    ON t_types.type = v_documents.document_type_name
```

If there are duplicates in `t_types`, then you need to use this instead...

```
SELECT
  v_documents.*
FROM
  v_documents
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT type FROM t_types GROUP BY type
)
  AS t_types
    ON t_types.type = v_documents.document_type_name
```

As a side benefit, as the number of types in `t_types` increases, each of these alternatives will often out perform use of `IN (SELECT)` any way.

**EDIT 2 :**

This shouldn't make any difference that I'm aware of, but what happens if you try this?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  v_documents
WHERE
  CONCAT('[', document_type_name, ']')
  IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('[', type, ']') FROM t_types)
```

Comment: Edited the question using a LEFT JOIN istead.

Comment: @MauroValvano - response added to answer, including some alternative approaches.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The second method worked. It's really strange.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * FROM v_documents WHERE UPPER(trim(document_type_name)) IN
    ( SELECT UPPER(trim(TYPE)) FROM t_types WHERE type IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: The op explicitly say that `t_types` do not contain any null values

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM v_documents
WHERE trim(document_type_name) IN
    ( SELECT trim(TYPE)
     FROM t_types);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but is not working. Still return 0 values.